# mmenu - newbee - no errors, just doesn't open?

Tags: jquery, css, mmenu

beginning to rework site to be responsive ... yeah yeah...
Anyway - have played with several menu plugins - all have worked but really like the look and robustness of mmenu so began playing with it.

All seems to load ok ... but it just never opens the menu?? Probably something REALLY silly but I'm just not seeing it...

the work page is here: http://devel.tennispensacola.com/index-mmenu.htm the mobile nav is displayed when the screen width is reduced, of course

have tried various arrangements of div id's and using "nav" instead of div etc. etc. .. also various js snipits to init things ... but, when I click the mobile menu open button - nothing happens?? any ideas would be GREAT! I'd really like to use mmenu for this one ... maybe replace the old non-mobile menu on the site with it as well but need to get it working first HA HA!

Thanks - Kicker

Comment: As per the tutorial site - http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorial.php you need to have the `a` tag that opens the menu point to the menu ID. So change `<a href="#nav">` to `<a href="#mobile_nav">`

Comment: Thanks Nick - I SWEAR I had tried that but was trying again just now - I guess while you responded - looks good now - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i look in your source code i see this:

```
<style>
#mobile-header {display: none; background-color: #4c4c4c;}
.mobile_nav {display: none;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 585px) {
#mobile-header {display: block;}
#navDiv {display: none;}
/*.mobile_nav {display: block;}*/
}
</style>
```

Your mobile_nav wont go to display block because you forgot to remove the comment tags ( /* */ ).

Does this help??

Comment: Thanks mrijneveld - yes - actually, when uncommenting there, it just shows as a list at the top of the page - but solved now anyway - thanks for taking the time to look and respond!